# MVC3 with Npgsql and Entity Framework and .Net Framework 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model, npgsql

Well I would like to know if NpgSQL supports .NET framework 4 with EntityFramework, as I tried to use it with framework 4 and Microsoft.Data.Entity.CTP (code first approach) in my MVC3 application and I found no success unfortunately.

Also if any one could lead me to any posts or links on using ADO.NET in MVC3 instead of EntiyFramework would be really helpful.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Out of box no. There is some workaround with PostgreSQL and EF, but I gave up after many attempts to force it to work. I use Telerik OpenAccess ORM. For PostgreSQL is free because database is also free. It's work with every major RDBMS. Support for Code first approach, and also database first approach (reverse enginering). In last version there is also Perfomance and tuning tool! Excellent product.

[Here is link](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you asked the question I think the answer would have been no. The answer is probably irrelevant to you now but for others ...

Now I would have to say the answer is **yes**. I have a MVC3 (then upconverted to MVC4) project that uses code first entity framework and npgsql.

I used EF6b2 and npgsql 2.0.12.

Setting the web.config entityframework section, DbProviderFactories section and connectionstring correctly was the part the got it working. I also included the security and npgsql dlls in the project.

See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12033304/25372