# Adding database server information in C# application

Tags: c#, postgresql, c#-4.0, desktop-application

I am using the following connection string in my c# application to communicate to my database which is hosted locally.

```
string conn = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" +
                                "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                "localhost", "5432", "postgres",
                                "postgres", "table");
NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
connection.Open();
NpgsqlCommand sqlcmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM public.roads", connection);
NpgsqlDataReader r = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Is there a way I can add the server information in config.app file and access it in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Entity Framework + PostgreSQL from connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322635/how-to-use-entity-framework-postgresql-from-connection)

Comment: Saw the link earlier but couldn't relate it to my problem.

Comment: yes add that in app.config or web.config file. And access that by configuration manager

Comment: @BhubanShrestha thanks for your comment. Can you provide me with a link or any resource related to this. I am new to c# development.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/

You need to add reference to configuration manager to access connection string in config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files).

In the app/web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  (...)
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Name1" connectionString="..." />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In the code:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name1"].ConnectionString;
```

Please note that the benefit of using `connectionStrings` section and not the `appSettings` is that if you're using an object-relational mapping framework there may be a support for using the connection string by name.

e.g.

```
public class RepositoryContext: DbContext
{
    public RepositoryContext() : base("Name1") 
    {
        (...)
    }
```

Comment: Had to add {using System.Configuration;} in start and it worked like a charm.